# Installation extension functions to pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to find sql source of functions `routing_dd.sql`
and `routing_dd_wrappers.sql`

I'm working on Windows 7 32bit.
The only one link to that [wrote by Underdark](http://anitagraser.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/) is empty:

*Both are available through the **project repository at Github**. Get them and execute them in your pgRouting-enabled database. Now, you should be ready.*

I need to create these functions in Postgres 9.2, Postgis 2.0 and pgRouting.

When I use drivingDistance in pgRouting layer plugin in QGIS 2.0 - that mark all nodes on map only, without visible errors.

Thanks for answer. Tom

Answer (score 2):

Installing pgRoutingfor PostGIS 2.0 works differently than described in the old post that you linked. For newer instructions check [pgRouting 2.0 for Windows quick guide](http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/).

Since you mention that pgRouting Layer plugin does work, I would assume that you actually installed everything correctly. If you clarify which settings you are using, we might be able to explain the behavior.

Comment: thanks fo answer and help.
Now I have the full funcionality of pgRouting, I guess...
Problem was in the function name: pgr_distancedriving not distance_driving
Tom

Comment: pgRouting layer plugin marks nodes with 'cost' <= 'distance', can You make small :-) upgrade to export marked nodes to shp with ID and costs? It would be great. Tom

Comment: @tomsik Please open a feature request ticket on  Github so this request does not get lost.